# how to load a webpage inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to load a web web page inside a div with an ajax call but not working. it's showing this error

*jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience*

how to solve this issue.

```
<div class="warper">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" data-target="home">Home</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="pageOne">Page One</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="pageTwo"> Page Two</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="pageThree">Page Three</a>
    </div>



  <div id="content"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#content").load('home.html');
        // Set trigger and container variables
        var trigger = $('.menu a'),
            container = $('#content');

        // Fire on click
        trigger.on('click', function () {
            // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
            var $this = $(this),
                target = $this.data('target');

            // Load target page into container
            container.load(target + '.html');

            // Stop normal link behavior
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to load a webpage into your webpage then `<iframe>` would be easier. Otherwise if your Server support PHP then `<?php include ?>` would be smarter aswell and not depending on scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be specific, you're trying to load **content** into a div, not a **webpage**. A webpage would have it's own `document` and `DOM` and such and would require an `<iframe>`

Your issue could be with your use of [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data-element-key-value) instead of [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName). Although in my answer I use the vanilla javascript [.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), which does the same thing and saves a jquery call. Essentially you're code is trying to :

```
container.load(undefined + '.html');
```

I've never used the load method like this, (I don't know why they decided to overload it for [event handeling](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/load/)) but it would look something like this:

```
<script>
  $('#content').load('home.html');

  $('.menu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop normal link behavior

    $('#content').load(this.getAttribute('data-target') + '.html');
  });
</script>
```

Also, if your script is at the bottom of the `<body>`, you don't need `$(document).ready()`, as the code won't run until the document is ready anyway.